# Understanding a monad instance

Tags: haskell, monads

I have this Haskell code portion:

```
newtype State st a = State (st -> (st, a))

instance Monad (State state) where
    return x = let f t = (t,x) in State f

    State f >>= g = State (\oldstate ->
                let {(newstate, val) = f oldstate;
                  State f'= g val}
                in f' newstate)
```

I'm new to monad but i think i got how `return` and `bind` works in the general case.

But in the example above i have lots of problems:

1. in `Monad (State state)` is State the Monad's name? How is it
   related with the `newtype State ...` ?
2. in `return x = let f t = (t,x) in State f` where does `t` comes from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So by this point you've certainly heard of *currying* or *partial application*: if you have `f :: a -> b -> c` and `x :: a`, then `f x :: b -> c`.  I.e., If `f` is a two-argument function and `x` has the type of `f`'s first argument, then `f x` is a function that takes the second argument and "completes" the application.

Well, in Haskell the same thing applies to type constructors like `State`.  Types and type constructors have a *kind*, which is analogous to how values have types.  A non-parametric type like `Integer` has kind `*`; a one-parameter type like `Maybe` has kind `* -> *`; `State` has kind `* -> * -> *`.

And then, `State state` is a partial application of the `State` type constructor, and has kind `* -> *`.  `Monad` is a class that applies to the kind `* -> *`.  So, applied to our examples:

1. `instance Monad (Integer) where ...` is forbidden because `Integer` has kind `*`.
2. `instance Monad (Maybe) where ...` is allowed because `Maybe` has kind `* -> *`.
3. `instance Monad (State) where ...` is forbidden because `State` has kind `* -> * -> *`.
4. `instance Monad (State st) where ...` is allowed  because `State st` has kind `* -> *`.

How do we know that `Monad` applies to types of kind `* -> *`?  We can infer it from the class declaration:

```
class Monad m where
    return :: a -> m a
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
    -- ...
```

Look at how `m` is used in this class declaration: as part of `m a` and `m b`, i.e., as taking one argument.  Because of this, Haskell infers that `m` is a type variable of kind `* -> *`.

Compare to this:

```
class Num a where
    (+) :: a -> a -> a
    (-) :: a -> a -> a
    -- ...
```

Here the type variable `a` is not applied to other type variables—thus it must be of kind `*`.

So strictly speaking, `State` is not a monad; it's a two-place type constructor that, when partially applied to just one type, gives you a monad.  So `State state` is a monad, as is `State Integer`, `State [a]`, etc.  People do often speak loosely and talk of `State` and similar things as monads, though, but you should understand it's a *parametrized* monad—it's a monad that has an internal type parameter and thus many variants that differ in the type of that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

1. `State` is the type of the monad, `instance Monad (State state)` is declaring `State state` (where `state` is a type variable that can be set to any other type*) to be an instance of `Monad`.  `newtype State` is the definition of the `State` type.
2. `let f t = (t, x)` is defining a *function*, with an argument named `t`.

* Technically, `state` is a type variable of kind `*`, but don't worry about that.